# How to specify where to save a YAML Pipeline?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

We have started creating CI Pipelines in Azure DevOps using YAML.  Here's the process:

1. Our "DevOps guy" has created some template .yml files.
2. For a project we want to use yaml for, we download the appropriate template .yml file into our repo where the .sln file resides and make sure it's named "azure-pipelines.yml".
3. In DevOps, then, we go to Create New Pipeline > Azure Repos GIT (YAML) > Select our repository > then "Existing Azure Pipelines YAML file" > select the file we had saved to the repo, and save the pipeline.

DevOps automatically saves the pipeline under our root folder.

But we don't want that - we want the pipelines to get saved under a specific folder in the hierarchy that was set up.

After saving the pipeline, I can go to Rename/move to manually move it at that point...but it would be nice to not have to add this step.

How can we do that?  Is that some setting somewhere in DevOps for an Admin (our "DevOps guy") to set?

Comment: Rename the pipeline?

Comment: @DanielMann After saving the pipeline, then I can go to Rename/move and move it....is there any way to have it automatically save to the folder we want, instead of adding this step to move it after saving it?

Comment: I think Azure DevOps don't have that option to do it currently. Sure you can raise a ticket with them if they get enough votes they can implement. I do agree the current process they have is not great. @Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mystic Groot actually answered the question by explaining that it currently can't be done.  I did submit a feedback suggestion to Microsoft via their forum for that.

@Nick Graham provided a nice workaround for in the meantime.  So you can either go to "New pipeline" from the folder you want it in, or use "Rename/move" after creating it to put it where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

In your folder structure click the ellipses (...) next to your folder to display a drop down menu that will let you create a pipeline in that folder.

[image]

Comment: That is at least easier than moving it after the fact.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Andy, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)